# Cisco ASA Outside to Outside NAT (forward from one public ip to another public IP)

Tags: routing, nat, cisco-asa

I have an ASA (A) with a set of public IPs (A1..A6). And I have another server S with a public IP (S1) .

I want all traffic to A2:22 NATed (forwarded) to S1:22.  (SSH is just an example here)
If possible I want the traffic to not even touch the inside interface.

(How) can I do that?

I tried:

```
  access-list outside_access_in line 26 extended permit tcp any host S1 eq ssh 

  access-list outside_access_in line 26 extended permit tcp any host S1 eq ssh 
  static (outside,outside)  A2 S1 netmask 255.255.255.255 tcp 0 0 udp 0
```

But that, according to the packet tracer, always dies on the implicit incoming drop rule on the outside interface. I even tried to satisfy it by using a "drop all your pants" any:any rule, with no luck.

I am aware that this is not enough to really make it work. But can it actually work?

Comment: Could you dump the *show run* with IP obfuscated? It would be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that intra interface traffic is allowed.

```
sh run | i same-security-traffic
```

If it isn't, then issue the following command:

```
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
```

It will allow traffic to arrive and leave the firewall on the same interface (hairpining).

Also, your static nat shouldn't be necessary since the traffic won't go accross any interfaces.

Comment: I think NAT would still be necessary, so I have control over the routing of the responses, and checking that box didn't cut it. (yeah I am using ASDM, I admit it :) )

Comment: A NAT rule will not affect routing (unless you are using FWSM).